# Can HTML 5 really do Win 32call?

Tags: c, delphi, winapi, html

In this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ThinVnc.aspx it says:

> ThinVNC is not a traditional VNC, as
>   it does not implement the AT&T RFB
>   protocol. Instead, it is built on top
>   of today's web standards: AJAX, JSON
>   and HTML5.

But when looking at the code, it seems like Delphi to me so can someone explains what the sentence above does really mean: is HTML 5 really capable of making OS call ?

```
TWin = class(TObject)
private
  Wnd : Hwnd;
  Rect : TRect;
  Pid : Cardinal;
public
  constructor Create(AWnd:HWND;ARect:TRect;APid:Cardinal);
end;

function EnumWindowsProc(Wnd: HWnd; const obj:TList<TWin>): Bool; export; stdcall;
var ProcessId : Cardinal;
  R,R1 : TRect;
  Win : TWin;
begin
  Result:=True;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd,ProcessId);
  if IsWindowVisible(Wnd) and not IsIconic(wnd)then begin
    GetWindowRect(Wnd,R);
    IntersectRect(R1,R,Screen.DesktopRect);
    if not IsRectEmpty(R1) then begin
      win := TWin.Create(Wnd,R,ProcessId);
      obj.Add(win);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure GetProcessWindowList(WinList:TList<TWin>);
begin
  WinList.Clear;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, Longint(WinList));
end;
```

Comment: note: the correct spelling is HTML5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely not, HTML5 is rendered by a browser and it has no way of connecting to any operating system kernels.

And your code is indeed Delphi. From reading the code posted above, this does screen capturing. I guess you'll have to read other source code to see where HTML 5 fits in all of this.

**Edit** You've looked at the screen capturing feature of ThinVNC (the HTML5 Remote Desktop). The **full** blog illustrating this can be found [here](http://csdevteam.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 6):

No, HTML5 can not. What you are looking at is, indeed, Delphi.

That article is fairly poorly written in my opinion and doesn't make it clear that you're looking at the "VNC Server" code rather than the client application (which would be the HTML5/JS portion).